# Flutter Grid View Builder Image network

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am facing an issue while loading an image from server. when the new screen is loaded it says an error " Valid Value range is empty:0 " but as soon as i reload the application it shows me the image perfectly

First time when i enter the screen
"The following RangeError was thrown building Gallery(dirty, state: _GalleryState#2db02):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0"

after I reload the application error is gone and it shows me the image correctly

Please take a look at my code

```
galleryLoad(
  String uid) async {
EasyLoading.show(status: "Fetching Images");
var url = '${serverPath}restaurantsGalleryImages';
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': "application/json",
  'Authorization': "Bearer $uid",
 };
  var body = json.encoder.convert({});

   var response = await http
      .post(Uri.parse(url), headers: requestHeaders, body: body)
      .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 30));
   dprint('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
   // dprint('Response body: ${response.body}');
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    EasyLoading.showSuccess("Images Fetched");
     var jsonResult = json.decode(response.body);
    images=jsonResult['images'];
    print(images.length);
  } else
    print("statusCode=${response.statusCode}");

   }
    @override
   void initState() {
     // TODO: implement initState
   galleryLoad(account.token);
    super.initState();
     }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 print("https://nearxt.com/admin/public/${images[0]['image'].toString()}");  // **Error 
     Directs me to this location**
 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Gallery",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
   ),

  body: Container(
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    child: **Image.network("https://nearxt.com/admin/public/${images[0] 
      ['image'].toString()}"),**
    )
   );
  }
```

Comment: Error Log
#0  List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
#1      _GalleryState.build (package:delivery_owner/ui/main/MainGallery.dart:84:52)